# How can we store previous value of some variable in some other variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I would like to access the previous value of `num1` in other function by storing it in another variable.
I have tried many ways without success; can you guys help me.

```
import random
num2 = 3
    
def token():
    global num2 
    print (num2) #It should print previous value of num1 (it is not giving previous value but giving me the same value with num1 every time )
    num1 = random.randint(40,90)
    print(num1) 
    num2= num1 

def vcode():
    print(num2) #want to access here the previous value of num1 

print(token(),vcode())
```

Comment: When I copy and paste this code and repeatedly call `token()`, it seems to behave like I would expect. It prints 3 and then a random number; then it prints the random number from the previous invocation and a new random number; and so on. It seems like num2 is in fact maintaining "whatever num1 was the last time `token()` was called". What's it supposed to be doing differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy `num1` into `num2` *before* changing the value of `num1`.  The following code will print the value and the previous value a few times.  Note that I removed `print` statments from your functions and added `return` values; you were trying to use the return values in the main program but not actually returning anything.

```python
import random
num1 = 3
    
def token():
    """
    generate and return a new value for num1, and 
    save the previous value in num2
    """
    global num1, num2 
    num2 = num1 
    num1 = random.randint(40,90)
    return num1

def vcode():
    """
    return the existing value of num2 (which token() 
    saved as the previous value of num1)
    """
    return num2

print(token(), vcode()) 
print(token(), vcode()) 
print(token(), vcode())
```

This gives:

```
46 3
63 46
51 63
```

By the way, the more convenient way to implement this would probably be to use a class, like this, rather than use your global variables.  The class instance contains both the current and previous value.

```
import random


class Token():

    def __init__(self, starting_value):
        self.num1 = starting_value
        self.num2 = None

    def get_value(self):
        self.num2 = self.num1
        self.num1 = random.randint(40,90)
        return self.num1

    def get_previous_value(self):
        return self.num2

t = Token(3)

for _ in range(3):
    print(t.get_value(), t.get_previous_value())
```

Again, this gives something similar:

```
72 3
69 72
80 69
```

Comment: Well I have very similar problem with my django project. I have asked question today and i didnt get answer by some one check that question and maybe you can answer that. Thank you

Comment: Maybe. What is the link to the question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63865929/user-is-unable-to-active

Comment: by the way can you tell me how can I access a variable from one class function to another class function

Comment: If your variables are saved as instance variables (in this case `self.num1` and `self.num2`) then they are accessible between different functions. But if a variable is local to one function, then you cannot access it in another function, even if both of those functions are methods of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value of the other function. One method (illustrated below) is you should return the value from one and access it in the other by calling this function:

```
import random
num2 = 3
    
def token():
    global num2 
    print (num2) 
    num1 = random.randint(40,90)
    print(num1) 
    num2= num1 
    return num2

def vcode():
    num2=token() 
    print(num2)

print(token(),vcode())
```